# $a^{(p-1)/2} \equiv \pm 1 \pmod p$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Show that if $a$ is any integer not divisible by $p$, then $a^{(p-1)/2}\equiv \pm 1 \pmod p$.

I know one wants to use Fermat's Little Theorem which states if $a$ is any integer not divisible by $p$, then $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$.

I was considering starting off with this and taking the square root of both sides; however, trouble can occur when $a^{(p-1)/2}$ is not a perfect square, and I'm not sure how to handle this.

Answer (score 4):

Use a difference of squares factorization: $$a^{p-1}-1=\left[a^{(p-1)/2}-1\right]\cdot\left[a^{(p-1)/2}+1\right]\equiv 0\pmod{p},$$ so $p$ divides one of the two factors. It follows that $a^{(p-1)/2}\equiv\pm 1\pmod{p}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\text{Put }\displaystyle a^{\frac{p-1}2}=b\implies b^2\equiv1\pmod p$$ using Fermat's Little Theorem

Now I don't want to repeat [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484165/number-theory-lemma-x2-equiv-1-pmod-p-implies-x-equiv-pm-1-pmod-p) argument